# how to connect 2 flutter app into a single drf api

Tags: flutter, django-rest-framework, real-time, sametime

Hi I am having a project where I have 2 flutter apps which is connected to a django rest framework api it worked fine locally in emulators but I find it difficult when I give it same lan ip address and test it in mobile phones only 1 app works

i typed ipconfig and gave both flutter apps same ip address and runned drf on 0.0.0.0:8000,cors allowed for all,checked the allowed host i am expecting the 2 apps to work at the same realtime

Comment: Two different processes can't occupy the same IP+port combination on the same computer. Once is probably not working.